# error function for add cart

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have written this code for add cart to payment. while clicking buttons that cart will be  add. but I got undefined syntax error

```
If(isset($_POST) && ($_POST[‘GET_PAYMENT’] == ‘1’))
{

    $totalAmount = $_POST[‘GET_PAYMENT’]; //Total amount
    $checkbox_id = $_POST[‘VALUE’]; // The radio button value 

        /* Here get the amount values (3,5.5 or 10) from 

    Database based on the $checkbox_id and store it in

    $amount variable*/


    $total_amount = $amount + $totalAmount;


    Echo $total_amount;

}
```

I got the error on above the page also I got a error in JS function

Javascript function

```
Function getPaymentVal()
{

Var checkboxVal = ‘’;

checkboxVal = $("input[@name=’rmr’]:checked").val();

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "ajax.php",
   data: "GET_PAYMENT=1&VALUE=”+ checkboxVal,
   success: function(total_amount)
   {
$(‘#totalamount’).val(total_amount);  

$(‘#repair_total_amount’).html(“Total <span class="repair-finalamount-txt">&pound;&nbsp;”+ total_amount+”</span>”);

$(function() {
  $("input[name='rmr']").change(function() {
    var val = parseInt($(this).val(), 10) ;
    alert("Typeof val: " + typeof(val));
  });
});
```

Can anyone re-correct my code?

Comment: Hi magna, could you specify what error you are getting in both situations, and in which line?

Comment: am getting undefined syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if all your brakets match, uncomment parts of the code where you think that there might be an error. Put parts of the code back in, until you notice that the error occurs. The latest added part of the code is the area where the error occurs.

This is the ways of the debugging jedi. May the force be with you.

write your 'if' statement in small letters, 'function' as well, as well as 'var', same goes for 'echo'.

Answer (score 1):

You have various syntax errors, capitalization and quotes, e.g. `‘’` or `“”` instead of `''` or `""` along with a missing `}` for your `success` and `getPaymentVal()` function overall.

The php corrected:

```
if(isset($_POST) && ($_POST["GET_PAYMENT"] == '1'))
{
    $totalAmount = $_POST["GET_PAYMENT"];
    $checkbox_id = $_POST["VALUE"];
    $total_amount = $amount + $totalAmount;
    echo $total_amount;
}
```

And the same with JavaScript:

```
function getPaymentVal() {
  var checkboxVal = $("input[name='rmr']:checked").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: {GET_PAYMENT:1,VALUE:checkboxVal},
    success: function(total_amount) {
      $('#totalamount').val(total_amount);  
      $('#repair_total_amount').html("Total <span class='repair-finalamount-txt'>&pound;&nbsp;"+total_amount+"</span>");
      $("input[name='rmr']").change(function() {
        var val = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        alert("Typeof val: " + typeof(val));
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Also note that `input[@name='rmr']` should be `input[name='rmr']` unless you're using jQuery < 1.3, in which the `@` was removed from [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/).